# Authenticate user & call REST API sharepoint on-premise using token

Tags: c#, .net-core, sharepoint-api, sharepoint-2016

I'm working on a .net core web application.
I need to call REST apis of a sharepoint on-premise site.

I can do it using some methods, but they all require to hardcode username and password.

I did it with a sharepoint online site & Azure AD. But i don't find a solution for on-premise..

Is there a way to authenticate user and get an access token to call REST apis ?

Edited for information :

As i need to get information on behalf on the current user. i Did not found a solution yet, for a .net core web app.

But i can do that by using CSOM in a .net standard web app.

Thanks for helps.
Tristan Sébillet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a appsettings.json file. Inside you will need something like:

```
"AuthClientId": (ID HERE)
"AuthClientSecret":(PIN / CODE HERE)
"AuthSubscriptionKey":(SUBSCRIPTION HERE)
"AuthRedirectUri": (REDIRECT HERE)
```

Comment: Can you explain more precisely ?